# How do you create a rails migration generator in a ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, migration

Im creating a simple Rails 2.3.8 gem and need a migration file inside it.  I following this structure:

```
/
/generators
/generators/conductor_migration
/generators/conductor_migration/conductor_migration_generator.rb
/generators/conductor_migration/templates
/generators/conductor_migration/templates/conductor_migration.rb
```

but when I install the gem in my app and run script/generate conductor_migration i says it cant find the migration.

Any thoughts?

Comment: can't find the migration or the generator ? Because script/generate found a generator, not a migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's a bug in bundler for 2.3.8.  I received a note from them yesterday saying that you can't access generators in gems that are local with bundler in 2.3.X you need to install them from the server.  Lovely.